# Re-routing with iptables

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, routing

When x.x.x.x makes a request on port 80 to y.y.y.y I would like the request to be redirected to z.z.z.z:80. Is it possible to do this by adding rules to iptables on y.y.y.y?

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use DNAT to rewrite the destination IP address, something like this:

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -s x.x.x.x -d y.y.y.y --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination z.z.z.z:80`

Comment: For this to work you also need to enable IPv4 forwarding. `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

Comment: Plus, if x.x.x.x, y.y.y.y, and z.z.z.z are in the same subnet, a `-j SNAT` rule will also be necessary.

Comment: I haven't done anything with SNAT yet - maybe I need to, x.x.x.x and y.y.y.y are on the same network? Initially the connection times out and after `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` it fails more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Final solution as follows:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -s x.x.x.x -d y.y.y.y --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination z.z.z.z:80
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

where eth0 is outside interface on y.y.y.y.